# AutoCAD 2014: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80029C4A) (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I have created classLibrary dll in vb.net 2013 for AutoCAD 2013 using ObjectARX 2013. It works fine in AutoCAD 2013 32bit & 64 bit (winxp, win7, win8). The same program I copied for AutoCAD 2014 and libraries used ObjectARX 2014. But it give this error when I run in AutoCAD 2014.

Please help me. What should I do?

```
Application does not support just-in-time (JIT)
debugging. See the end of this message for details.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80029C4A): Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.VBBinder.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Type objType, IReflect objIReflect, Object target, Object[] args, String[] namedParameters)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at PV3D.Module1.Head(Double ID, Double thk)
   at PV3D.Form1.Button1_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Acdbmgd
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AcdbMgd.DLL
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
AdApplicationFrame
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.19.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AdApplicationFrame.DLL
----------------------------------------
AdWindows
    Assembly Version: 4.0.24.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.24.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AdWindows.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsBase
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/PresentationCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xaml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xaml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero2
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero2/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
accoremgd
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/accoremgd.DLL
----------------------------------------
Acmgd
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/Acmgd.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
AcWindows
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AcWindows.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcCui
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AcCui.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemXml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemXml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsFormsIntegration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsFormsIntegration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsFormsIntegration.dll
----------------------------------------
AcWindows.resources
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/en-US/AcWindows.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationUI
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationUI/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationUI.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll
----------------------------------------
PV3D
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Fayaz%20Memon/AppData/Roaming/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/PV3D.bundle/Contents/PV3D.dll
----------------------------------------
FeaturedAppsPlugin
    Assembly Version: 19.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.0.55.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/ProgramData/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/Autodesk%20FeaturedApps.bundle/Contents/Windows/2014/FeaturedAppsPlugin.dll
----------------------------------------
ContextualTabSelectorRules
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AcWindows.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Expression.Interactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.20520.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.DLL
----------------------------------------
ManagedMC3
    Assembly Version: 7.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 7.2.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/ManagedMC3.DLL
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationTypes
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationTypes/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationTypes.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.50709.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
AcLivePreviewContext
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AcWindows.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationProvider
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationProvider/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationProvider.dll
----------------------------------------
AcLayer
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AcLayer.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcLayer.resources
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/en-US/AcLayer.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Luna
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Luna/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Luna.dll
----------------------------------------
AcMrUi
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AcMrUI.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcMrUi.resources
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/en-US/AcMrUi.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcMr
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/AcMr.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Serialization
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Serialization/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
----------------------------------------
FeaturedAppsPlugin.resources
    Assembly Version: 19.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.0.55.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/ProgramData/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/Autodesk%20FeaturedApps.bundle/Contents/Resources/en-US/FeaturedAppsPlugin.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop
    Assembly Version: 19.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 19.1.18.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202014/Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
Application does not support Windows Forms just-in-time (JIT)
debugging. Contact the application author for more
information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with AutoCAD (or any other interop) that is likely to change version numbers between development and production or even bitness (x64 vs x86) it is better to use dynamics in C# (object in VB) rather than using references.

In order to have the accurate properties and methods in AutoCAD, you can a dummy project that references the ObjectARX dlls, and then a CAD class that abstracts all access to AutoCAD using objects (formerly variants, and dynamics in C#). I use the dummy project to get the correct spellings for the methods and properties, and then apply the same calls to my actual CAD project

So to get the application object I use:

```
dynamic _application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application");
dynamic _document = _application.ActiveDocument // Or _application.Documents.Open("...")
```

VB

```
object application = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application") ' or CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application"
object document = application.ActiveDocument ' Or _application.Documents.Open("...")
```

The class ID passed to the GetActiveObject method : "AutoCAD.Application" will return the active or last installed version of AutoCAD. So on a machine with multiple versions, you can specify the version you want by specifying the version number in the class ID like this: "AutoCAD.Application.19". You'll need to carry out some research to know what the number should be.

By encapsulating all the AutoCAD features I need in my CAD class, I can call CAD.Line(....), CAD.InsertBlock(...).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help.
Actually I installed two versions of AutoCAD (2013 & 2014). This problem was due to confliction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure what DLL is failing, try hooking up to the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event and step through the code that causes the assembly to load.

Also be sure to check that if you're running a service pack update to AutoCAD 2014 that your ObjectARX SDK references have the updated dlls.